# Bread Crumb - WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a site that is in wordpress that has a custom navigation. The site also does not use categories. My question is there away to create bread crumb from the custom navigation. I can dump out the information from the post by passing the post ID to a get_post($id), but I cannot see a relationship to previous links. I also looked in the wordpress database and did not see any relationship between the previous post.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

First, if you are using wordpress.com they will have breadcrumb plugins. And they also exist for wordpress hosted sites and I'm sure wordpress.com home-made sites.

However, if you want to create the breadcrumb functionality from scratch, here's the link to the breadcrumb code from  TheWebTaylor  Wordpress site (it's long so I used the link rather than copy & paste): https://www.thewebtaylor.com/articles/wordpress-creating-breadcrumbs-without-a-plugin

To call the crumbs on your page use:

```
<?php custom_breadcrumbs(); ?>
```

Disclaimer:  I have not tested this code, and please read the disclaimer at the bottom of the linked webpage.

Answer (score 0):

Install the Yoast SEO plugin:
https://yoast.com/wordpress/plugins/seo/

Instructions on how to implement breadcrumbs using Yoast SEO:
https://kb.yoast.com/kb/implement-wordpress-seo-breadcrumbs/

```
<?php
if ( function_exists('yoast_breadcrumb') ) {
yoast_breadcrumb('
<p id="breadcrumbs">','</p>
');
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Create Breadcrumbs:**
We’ve created a custom function called get_breadcrumb() to generate the breadcrumb links. You only need to add the get_breadcrumb() function code in functions.php file of the current theme.

1-Step) Copy Below Code in your theme functions.php file

```
function get_breadcrumb() {
    echo '<a href="'.home_url().'" rel="nofollow">Home</a>';
    if (is_category() || is_single()) {
        echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&#187;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
        the_category(' &bull; ');
            if (is_single()) {
                echo " &nbsp;&nbsp;&#187;&nbsp;&nbsp; ";
                the_title();
            }
    } elseif (is_page()) {
        echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&#187;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
        echo the_title();
    } elseif (is_search()) {
        echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&#187;&nbsp;&nbsp;Search Results for... ";
        echo '"<em>';
        echo the_search_query();
        echo '</em>"';
    }
}
```

**Display Breadcrumbs:**
Call the get_breadcrumb() function in single.php file and others files where you want to display the breadcrumbs on your WordPress site.

2- STEP) Paste below code where you want to show breadcrumb  for example (header.php)

```
<div class="breadcrumb"><?php get_breadcrumb(); ?></div>
```

**Styling Breadcrumbs:**
This CSS helps to style the breadcrumbs links.

3- STEP) Paste Below CSS

```
.breadcrumb {
    padding: 8px 15px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
.breadcrumb a {
    color: #428bca;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```